# incopatible types: cannot be converted to

Tags: java, javafx

I have a class, `NewBeautifulKiwi`, that has getters and setters.

When I try to set the:

```
public void setKiwi(String Kiwi) {
    this.Kiwi = Kiwi;
}
```

with values from a TextField like:

```
@FXML
TextField KIWITextField;
NewBeautifulKiwi newBeautifulKiwi = new NewBeautifulKiwi()
    .setKiwi(KIWITextField.getText());
```

I get the error message:
    ***incopatible types: cannot be converted to NewBeautifulKiwi***

Here are the classes in full (the necessary extracts for this question)

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import wakiliproject.Forms.AddNew.DB.NewBeautifulKiwi;

public class SampleController implements Initializable, ControlledScreen {

    @FXML
    TextField KIWITextField;
    NewBeautifulKiwi newBeautifulKiwi = new NewBeautifulKiwi().setKiwi(KIWITextField.getText());
}


import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class NewBeautifulKiwi implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int KiwiId;
    private String Kiwi;

    public int getKiwiId() {
        return KiwiId;
    }

    public void setKiwiId(int KiwiId) {
        this.KiwiId = KiwiId;
    }

    public String getKiwi() {
        return Kiwi;
    }

    public void setKiwi(String Kiwi) {
        this.Kiwi = Kiwi;
    }
}
```

How can I pass the TextField value to the setter?

Comment: Is there a typo in your description of the error message, or is there a typo in the error message itself? If it's the latter, we should preserve the typo in your question so that others can find it.

Comment: _incopatible_ or _incompatible_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `new NewBeautifulKiwi().setKiwi(KIWITextField.getText());` is determined by the signature of `setKiwi`, which is: `public void setKiwi(String Kiwi)`.

So that expression returns nothing (void) and you can't assign it to a variable. You can either split the two statements:

```
NewBeautifulKiwi newBeautifulKiwi = new NewBeautifulKiwi();
newBeautifulKiwi.setKiwi(KIWITextField.getText());
```

Or use a fluent interface style (my personal preference in that case because it allows you to chain setters):

```
public NewBeautifulKiwi setKiwi(String Kiwi) {
    this.Kiwi = Kiwi;
    return this;
}

//Now that will compile
NewBeautifulKiwi newBeautifulKiwi = new NewBeautifulKiwi().setKiwi(KIWITextField.getText());
```

Comment: Hi [assylias](http://stackoverflow.com/users/829571/assylias). The second solution, fluent interface, works. The first doesn't. The errors I get with the second are:

 package newBeautifulKiwi does not exist,
 <identifier> expected,
 package KIWITextField does not exist.
 
What could be the problem?

Comment: @user3189827 Have you included the two lines in a method, inside a class? That error is typically due to missing brackets or statements not being enclosed in a method or multiple classes declarations in one file etc.

Comment: Wow! Thanks man. Now it works. I had to put the two statements in a method.

Answer (score 0):

```
NewBeautifulKiwi newBeautifulKiwi = new 
                             NewBeautifulKiwi().setKiwi(KIWITextField.getText());
```

Here `setKiwi` is void method. not returning any thing. You can change your code as follows

```
 new NewBeautifulKiwi().setKiwi(KIWITextField.getText());`
```

You can use your current code if your `setKiwi` method in following way.

```
public NewBeautifulKiwi setKiwi(String Kiwi) {
this.Kiwi = Kiwi;
return kiwi;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NewBeautifulKiwi newBeautifulKiwi = new NewBeautifulKiwi();
newBeautifulKiwi.setKiwi(KIWITextField.getText());
```